# How to wrap std::shared_ptr and std::vector from C++ in Cython?

Tags: c++, cython, shared-ptr, stdvector

I am trying to wrap a C++ library into a python API with Cython. The class I want to wrap has the following template:

```
template<typename Value>
class ClassToWrap
{

public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Value> > TypeToWrap;

    ClassToWrap(TypeToWrap data)
    {
    }
}
```

I'm not confident with C++ standard library. How I can wrap the `TypeToWrap` in Cython in a way that it can be inizialized in a simple way like an array or a multidimenstional array, for example with a for loop of assignments? Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: `in a way that it can be inizialized from a numpy array or a Python list of list?` can you elaborate on that statement ? do you want a numpy array of `ClassToWrap` or do you want the constructor of it to accept numpy arrays ? and have you taken a look at [wrapping c++](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html) ?

Comment: On top of my understanding the constructor should take a data structure that resemble a list of arrays or a bidimensional array.  My target is to fill it with a numpy array, but practically I would be happy to expose TypeToWrap in Cython in any way that could be easily filled with a for loop of assignments.

Comment: @AhmedAEK  Thanks For the reference to wrapping c++. I've read the book of Kurt W. Smith and I can handle the most basic case to wrap c++, but I struggle with real case scenario and complex data type because I don't have much experience with C++ libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let's assume you have a C++ header as follows:

```cpp
// cpp_class.h

#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template<typename Value>
class ClassToWrap
{
public:
    typedef std::shared_ptr<std::vector<Value> > TypeToWrap;

    ClassToWrap(TypeToWrap data) : obj(std::move(data))
    {
    }
private:
    TypeToWrap obj;
};
```

you would need to expose this class to cython, this is done by a `cdef extern` from  [cython wrapping Cpp](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html) documentation.

```py
# my_cy_class.pyx

# distutils: language = c++

from libcpp.memory cimport make_shared, shared_ptr
from libcpp.vector cimport vector

cdef extern from "cpp_class.h" nogil:
    cdef cppclass ClassToWrap[T]:
        ctypedef shared_ptr[vector[T]] TypeToWrap
        ClassToWrap(TypeToWrap)
        # define anything you intend to use
```

note that you only need to define the functions, not their implementations.

secondly, let's define a cython class to wrap it and expose it to python, since python is going to use it, it needs to know the type of `T`, let's assume it is an `int`:

```py
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref
from libcpp.utility cimport move

cdef class wrapper_class:
    cdef ClassToWrap[int]* wrapped_obj  # needs to be a defined type and heap allocated

    def __cinit__(self, some_list):
        cdef vector[int] v = some_list
        cdef ClassToWrap[int].TypeToWrap ptr = make_shared[vector[int]](move(v))
        self.wrapped_obj = new ClassToWrap[int](move(ptr))
        # deref(self.wrapped_obj).foo()

    def __dealloc__(self):
        del self.wrapped_obj
```

you may be wondering why a pointer to an object is used ? the reason is because your object has no default zero arguments constructor, and cython requires a default zero arguments constructor to be able to stack allocate it, using a `__cinit__` and a `__dealloc__` guarantee no memory leaks

note that `some_list` doesn't need to be a python list, it can easily be a numpy array, and knowing the type beforehand can help the compiler optimize the code for it, the following code can test it.

```py
import pyximport
script_args = ["--cython-cplus"]
setup_args = {
    "script_args": script_args,
    "include_dirs": ['.'],

}
pyximport.install(setup_args=setup_args, language_level=3,)

import numpy as np
import my_cy_class

inputs = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
a = my_cy_class.wrapper_class(inputs)
```

Comment: I think this is basically right but it might be worth trying to use the automatic python object -> vector conversion in Cython. I don't think the shared pointer stops you from doing this

Comment: @DavidW none of the methods i know will work in making cython automatically generate code for `object -> vector` conversion, do you know a way to do it ?

Comment: Maybe `deref(obj) = some_list`? Or `cdef vector[int] v = some_list; `make_shared[vector[int]](move(v))`? Something like that. I haven't tried either though

Comment: Thanks very much. I've implemented your answer and it's working both with some_list as python list or numpy.array.

Answer (score 1):

You should give the pointer to Python and create a bidirectional observing pattern (notify both sides) if an object is deleted! and you can reset the shared_ptr. i.e:

```
class CythonWrapClass {
 public:
  CythonWrapClass(std::shared_ptr<Foo> sharedFoo) : foo(sharedFoo) {
    // cython communication in the class anywhere
    // assume cython object variable in the class has name: cthon
    // cthon should take the pointer of Foo and work with it but when it has
    // finished it should notify to this pointer (exactly this instance)
    // when destroying notified from python it will decrease refcount
  }

  // cthon will call this function when it finished its job with sharedFoo
  void onDestroyFromcthon() { foo.reset(); }

 private:
  std::shared_ptr<Foo> foo;
};
```